# How in Pycharm change viev terminal?

Tags: pycharm

When writing in django and want see result in terminal, open python laucher/terminal, but i want result in inside Pycharm, how to do it?
When calling comand 'runserver' open another terminal
i new user and dont understand how do it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLXoJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7Oxc.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should type the whole command, that is:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Check the [tutorial link here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server)